# Условие в чанке modx

Tags: modx

Использую модуль FormIt. Шаблон формы имеет вид:

```
<select name="theme" value="[[!+fi.theme]]">
<option value="">Выберите тему...</option>
<option value="Жалоба" [[!+fi.theme:FormItIsSelected=`Жалоба`]]>Жалоба</option>
<option value="Предложение" [[!+fi.theme:FormItIsSelected=`Предложение`]]>Предложение</option>
</select>
```

В чанке все стандартно:

```
[[!AjaxForm?
    &snippet=`FormIt`
    &form=`tpl.AjaxForm.feedback`
    &hooks=`email`
    &emailSubject=`Выбор селекта`
    &emailTo=`first@test.com` ]]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу сделать условие в чанке по значению селекта с заменой мейла? Т.е. если значение селекта=Жалоба тогда emailTo=first@test.com, если селект=Предложение тогда emailTo=second@test.com. Гуглил, но синтаксис не понял, буду очень благодарен за подсказку. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать так:

в вызове сниппета в поле адресата пишем чанк:

```
&emailTo=`[[$addressTo]]`
```

содержимое чанка `addressTo`:

```
[[+fi.theme:eq=`Жалоба`:then=`first@test.com`:else=``]][[+fi.theme:eq=`Предложение`:then=`second@test.com`:else=``]][[+fi.theme:ne=`Жалоба`:and:if=`[[+fi.theme]]`:ne=`Предложение`:then=`error@test.com`:else=``]]
```

3-ий модификатор добавлен на случай отправки некорректной формы, когда не выбрана ни `Жалоба` ни `Предложение`

Answer (score 0):

Можно как вариант, значением `value` передавать нужный email:

```
...
<option value="first@test.com" [[!+fi.theme:FormItIsSelected=`Жалоба`]]>Жалоба</option>
<option value="second@test.com" [[!+fi.theme:FormItIsSelected=`Предложение`]]>Предложение</option>
...
```

Имя селекта `theme`, поэтому плэйсхолдер на выходе будет `[[+theme]]`.

Итого:

```
[[!AjaxForm?
    &snippet=`FormIt`
    &form=`tpl.AjaxForm.feedback`
    &hooks=`email`
    &emailSubject=`Выбор селекта`
    &emailTo=`[[+theme]]` ]]
```

Comment: В этом посетитель сайта увидит адрес куда идет письмо, это может быть нежелательно. А в случае отсутствия дополнительных проверок, недобросовестный посетитель меняя форму, может использовать ваш сервер для рассылки спама

Comment: @Tunker это да, согласен. Вариант с условием гораздо лучше.